# Set width of a <TD> when converting HTML to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

On button click I need to read the HTML file and convert it to PDF. The PDF is generating without any problem. But the width of columns in table is equally distributed when converted to PDF. But I need the first column of my table to take 70% of the total size of my table (540)

How can I do this?

**Template.html :**

```
 <table runat="server" id="header" border="3" width="540">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:70%; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
                <strong>Test Specification </strong>
            </td>
            <td style="width:10%; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
                <strong>GST </strong>
            </td>
            <td style="width:10%; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
                <strong>Service </strong>
            </td>
            <td style="width:10%; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
                <strong>Amount </strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Button click to convert HTML to PDF :**

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String htmlText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Template.htm");
      Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss tt") + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
      iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
            hw.Parse(new StringReader(HTML));
            document.Close();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(HTML);
    }
```

Comment: By the way: HTMLWorker is discontinued in favor of XML Worker: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html

Comment: That is true, but if you are stuck using the .NET 2.0 Framework, then you won't be able to use the new shiny things.

Comment: Just a quick note to say that if you have say 4 columns, but only put widths on the first 3 assuming that it'll work out the 4th. It won't you need the widths everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a combination of colspan and LoadTagStyle, both of which are outside the bounds of what I can fit in this textbox. To simplify, iTextSharp treats the total number of columns as 100% of the table, so a colspan of 5 on a table that is 10 columns should be treated like 50% of the table.

I have found that I have to play around with the values a bit, but hopefully that will lead you down the right path.

Comment: Just to add my 2 cents as I've found out the hard way - you can evidently not have any columns that have the width set be part of a `colspan` cell set.  In other words, if column 1 has a width set, and somewhere along the line you have column one's attribute `colspan='2'`, it breaks the width setting completely...

Answer (score 5):

you must set td width in percentage `<td width="10%">`  for td in each row, not only in header or first row.

Comment: Does not work on older versions of ITextSharp. Be sure to use the latest version!

Answer (score 5):

Use colspan property. If you have two cells defined as 10% and 90% for instance. Set colspan = 1 and 9 respectively.
It does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

set the width="70%" and it should work.

```
<td width="70%">
```

Answer (score 1):

> 

its dosent work.
there is no any way to set the table cell width.
im using unusual code for change the cell width.

with this sample code, you can find all tables and the find all rows.
if row has 2 columns, cell widths set to 400 and 100!

*you have to change the code for your project!

```
            foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
            {
                if (htmlElement is PdfPTable)
                {
                    var table = (PdfPTable)htmlElement;
                    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        PdfPCell[] pdfCellTemp = row.GetCells();
                        if (pdfCellTemp.Length == 2)
                        {
                            float[] w = { 400, 100 };
                            row.SetWidths(w);
                        }
                    }
                }
                pdfCell.AddElement(htmlElement);
            }
```